# Draw gantt chart using UIcollectionviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have research in forum satackovzrflow and I have found(Using a UICollectionViewController and my own UICollectionViewLayout subclass, I've put together a view that shows a Gannt style time chart. Using that framework to do the bands has been really easy of Travis Griggs) So How can I draw gantt chart Using UIcollectionviewController? Give me any idea to I can start draw it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dg6G.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to reinvent the wheel, you can check one of the library that draw charts on iOS and use it

Check the following Libraries

1. [IQ Widgets](https://github.com/evolvIQ/iqwidgets)
2. [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts)
3. [JBChartView](https://github.com/Jawbone/JBChartView)
4. [PNChart](https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart)

The first library `IQ Widgets` has a Gantt chart

Comment: Gantt chart it's not usual chart. This libraries do not allow present Gantt chart.

Comment: I added `IQ Widgets` to the list of libraries, which includes a Gantt chart

Comment: Hi Mahmound Adam I have added IQWidgets to my project! so how can i custom it in my project!

Comment: I think what you need is to create `IQGanttView` and add it to your view then use the method `-addRow:(id<IQCalendarDataSource>)row` to add your data, i.e. you will need to have a data structure that conforts to `IQCalendarDataSource` protocol

Comment: Hi, Have you tried this? I need to know that it's working for sure. Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two years ago I have same task. I have folders, and tasks. I done all staff with simple view and autoresizing mask. I go through all tasks, calculate frames and create view hierarchy with this frames. To draw arrows between tasks, I create overlay that draws arrows.

If you really want use `UICollectionView`, I recommend to you read about [custom layout](http://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/collection-view-layouts/).